# The user instance login flag is not allowed when connecting to a user instance of SQL Server. The connection will be closed

Tags: html, sql, asp.net, visual-studio

im working in Visual Studios 2013 and making a basic website. Im trying to make a simple sign up page with first name, last name, and id. Each time I try to connect to the database, I get this message:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in
>   System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

My sql command is:
`string sql = "insert into mytable(fname, lname, id) values('" + fname + "','" + lname + "','" + id + "')";
string filename = "Database.mdf";
MyAdoHelper.DoQuery(filename, sql);`

In the *MyAdoHelper* class the fucntion *DoQuery* is this:

```
public static void  DoQuery(string fileName, string sql)

{

    SqlConnection conn = ConnectToDb(fileName);
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    com.Dispose();
    conn.Close();

}
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: please include the code in question

Comment: Post the stacktrace of the exception too.

Comment: im a beginner and not sure what stacktrace of the exception is... but ill post the code

Answer (score 1):

Which option did you select on ***"Log on to the server"***?

Maybe you DID select it as ***"Use Windows Authentication"***

Please set User Instance as false.

For example connection String must be

```
Data Source=.\sqlexpress;AttachDbFilename=C:\...\xxx.mdf;User Instance=False;
```